# Why am I not getting an output to my program to find the minimum value in a given array in 8086 emulator?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to find the smallest value in a given array, and the code I used is this

```
MOV SI,500
MOV CL,[SI]
MOV CH,00
INC SI
MOV AL,[SI]
DEC CL
INC SI
L1:CMP AL,[SI]
JNC SKIP
MOV AL,[SI]
SKIP:INC SI
LOOP L1
MOV [600],AL
HLT
```

It compiles fine and runs fine, then I go to "aux" and then to "memory" to type in my input values. I set the address as 0100:0500 and then I give input "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" then against the first row, like this -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMyiU.png and i click update, and then "RUN" and then go to aux-->memory and check the address 0600, which is where i guess the output would be, and i get just zeroes, like this --- https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBcPd.png what is wrong with my code? why am i not getting the minimum value and just zeroes in 0600? I am a total beginner to the 8086 programming, please help.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't you need setting the `DS` segment register to 0100h on top of your program?

  You clearly expect to address memory at 0100h:0500h.
- Don't you have to use the hexadecimal suffix?

  `MOV SI,500` uses a decimal 500; you need `MOV SI,0500h` for hexadecimal!

  Note: If you're using a debugger then the hexadecimal notation could well be the default. If you're using a normal assembler then using the correct prefix or suffix is essential.
- The loop runs for much too long!

  ```
  MOV SI,500
  MOV CL,[SI]           <<<< If THIS reads 01 as is expected...
  MOV CH,00
  INC SI
  MOV AL,[SI]
  DEC CL                <<<< then THIS will produce 0
  INC SI
  L1:CMP AL,[SI]
  JNC SKIP
  MOV AL,[SI]
  SKIP:INC SI
  LOOP L1               <<<< So THIS runs 65536 times.
  MOV [600],AL
  HLT
  ```
- In order to find the **minimum** you will have to change the `jnc skip` instruction to `jb skip`. Currently you're looking for the **maximum**.

---

This is a version that you could try. As always: don't just copy but try to understand how it works.

```
  mov  ax, 0100h
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  si, 0500h
  mov  cx, 5      ;The number of values in the array
  mov  al, 255    ;This will become the mininum
L1:
  cmp  al, [si]
  jb   SKIP
  mov  al, [si]
SKIP:
  inc  si
  loop L1         ;This now runs 5 times.
  mov  [0600h], al
  hlt
```

It would be a good idea to try the code with data that is a bit more random. Perhaps use 3, 2, 5, 1, 4.